# Model attribute added by first handler not available in forwarded handler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, forward, modelattribute

I have a handler which sets a model attribute and forwards to another handler.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"forwardex"})
public String forwardex(Model map){
    map.addAttribute("forwardex", "forwarded");
    return "forward:forwarded";
}
```

In the handler called by the forward, I'm examing the model.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"forwarded"})
public String forwarded(Model model){
    for(String s:model.asMap().keySet()){
        System.out.println("key::"+s+"value::"+model.asMap().get(s));
    }
    return "result";
}
```

However, the attribute set in first handler, `forwardex`, isn't present.

In the returned `result` JSP, I am able to access it.

Does this mean that model attributes are specific to a method handler?

Comment: Can someone please comment ? Many thanks

Comment: could someone please help me on this,many thanks

Comment: @BalusC Many thanks for your initiative

Comment: @BalusC Could you please clear my doubt ?

Comment: @BalusC thanks for replying

Comment: @Please someone clear me on this ...